# Digest Auth Socket Server to Server

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

How can I realize digest authentication and subscription with sockets in a Server to Server application with PHP. What options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it with Symfony Silex, RatchetPHP and OAuth2.

I first get an OAuth access token from the Silex RestApi.

Then I pass it to the Ratchet websocket server as a url parameter when I open the connection, i.e `websocket.connect('ws://localhost:8482?access_token=L83pR5amKt')`.

I can retrieve it with Ratchet, and finally I know which user is authenticated behind the websocket connection.

Comment: Also, I used this trick in Sandstone. You may be interested, so here is the authentication documentation: https://eole-io.github.io/sandstone/authentication.html